# Magento Multi store customer account sharing

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I have a scenario where I have 3 store fronts on one Magento platform. I want to be able to share customer accounts across two of the store fronts but not the third. In System > Config > Customers > Customer Configuration you can Share Customer Accounts by "Per Website" or "Globally' but you can't select which websites individually.

I know I could change the store_id in the table customer_entity but that's not a long term option, has anyone been able to do the described another way?